# Name for $N^T A N$ when N is rectangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, quadratic-forms

According to wikipedia, a transformation of the form

$$A → P^T A P$$

is called a [congruence transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_transformation) when $P$ is invertible (and thus square).

I often run into transformations of the similar form

$$A → N^T A N$$

where $N$ is rectangular.

For example, this happens in optimization when $x^T A x$ defines a quadratic objective and then $x = N y$ is substituted to reparameterize over a linear (sub)space (e.g., enforce linear equality constraints).

Similar questions without answers:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405060/is-there-a-term-for-the-operation-of-multiplying-the-product-of-two-matrices-by
- [Does the form $XAX^\top$ have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367435/does-the-form-xax-top-have-a-name/3367651#3367651)

Comment: in some settings, we say that  a quadratic form represents  another, see http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Schulze_Pillot_2004.pdf  and generally http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/   This is similar to the statement that a form represents a number,  where now the number $n$  is both a one by one matrix  and the form $n x^2$   as needed. Not sure this would be useful if the ring involved were the real numbers.